# Tikz/addplot with gnuplot - graph of the function x^(-2/3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I would like to plot graph for function *x^(-2/3)* in the domain 1:2 and -2:-0.1. But for negative numbers I have got error (see below). I don't know, how can I set number format "%.7e" for gnuplot used in tikz command \addplot. Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

And next, I observe that gnuplot cannot plot function x^(-2/3), but only x^(-0.6666). I have got message *empty y range [1:1]*

**Xelatex Error:**

```
set format "%.7e";; set samples 100; set dummy x; plot [x=-2:-0.1] x**(-0.666); ^ 
%%"example.pgf-plot.gnuplot", line 2: all points y value undefined!
```

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, 
      every node/.style={transform shape} ]


    \begin{axis}[
      xmin = -1.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 3.5,  % osy
      domain = -1:3.5,
      restrict y to domain=0:3,
      axis equal image,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
      ]

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = 0.1:2] gnuplot{x^(-0.666)};

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = -2:-0.1] gnuplot{x^(-0.666)};


    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graph should be symmetric about the axis y, but it is not.

[image]

Comment: You have fallen for [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division).  Try `x^(2/3.)` instead (notice the decimal point).

Comment: Also, you cannot rise a negative number to a fractional power because fractional powers are defined in terms of a logarithm which is not defined for negative numbers (at least not in the real plane).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a limitation of mathematics itself.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot of `y=x^(-2/3)` is [not symmetric about the y axis](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%5E(-2%2F3)) (maybe you're actually trying to plot [`y=1/(cuberoot(x^2))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1%2Fcuberoot(x%5E2))?).

For negative values of `x`, you'll get a complex result. You can extract the real part of the result using gnuplot's `real` function, and plot that instead:

[image]

And in case you're actually trying to plot `y=1/(cuberoot(x^2))` (which is equal to `x^(2/3)` in the positive domain), you can use `1/(x^2)^(1./3)`. That gives you a function that's symmetric about the y axis:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, 
      every node/.style={transform shape} ]


    \begin{axis}[
      xmin = -2.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin = -3.5, ymax = 3.5,  % osy
      restrict y to domain=-3:3,
      axis equal image,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
      ]

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = 0.1:2] gnuplot{x^(-2.0/3)};

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = -2:-0.1] gnuplot{real(x^(-2.0/3))};


    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, 
      every node/.style={transform shape} ]


    \begin{axis}[
      xmin = -2.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin = -3.5, ymax = 3.5,  % osy
      restrict y to domain=-3:3,
      axis equal image,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
      ]

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = 0.1:2] gnuplot{1/((x^2)^(1./3))};

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = -2:-0.1] gnuplot{1/(x^2)^(1./3)};


    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```